# optimizing hourly statistics retrieval with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, optimization, pymongo, database

I've collected about 10 mio documents spaning a few weeks in my mongodb database, and I want to be able to calculate some simple statistics and output them. 
The statistics I'm trying to get is the average of the rating on each document within a timespan, in one hour intervals.

To give an idea of what I'm trying to do, follow this sudo code:

```
var dateTimeStart;
var dateTimeEnd;

var distinctHoursBetweenDateTimes = getHours(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);

var totalResult=[];

foreach( distinctHour in distinctHoursBetweenDateTimes )
    tmpResult = mapreduce_getAverageRating( distinctHour, distinctHour +1 )
    totalResult[distinctHour] = tmpResult;

return totalResult;
```

My document structure is something like:
{_id, rating, topic, created_at}

Created_at is the date I'm gathering my statistics based on (time of insertion and time created are not always the same)

I've created an index on the created_at field.

The following is my mapreduce:

```
map = function (){ 
    emit( this.Topic , { 'total' : this.Rating , num : 1 } ); 
};

reduce = function (key, values){  
    var n = {'total' : 0, num : 0}; 
    for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ){ 
        n.total += values[i].total; 
        n.num += values[i].num; 
    } 
    return n; 
};

finalize = function(key, res){ 
    res.avg = res.total / res.num; 
    return res; 
};
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done more effectively - possibly by letting mongo do more work, instead of running several map-reduce statements in a row.

At this point each map-reduce takes about 20-25 seconds so counting statistics for all the hours over a few days suddenly takes up a very long time.

My impression is that mongo should be suited for this kind of work - hence I must obviously be doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I assume the time is part of the documents you are MapReducing?

When you run the MapReduce over all documents, determine the hour in the map function and add it to the key you emit, you could do all this in a single MapReduce.

Comment: I might not be understanding this correctly - and as you can probably tell - I'm just learning about MapReduce.

However - based on the key and value provided to me in the map function - how will I know about the hour? Should I from the reduce function return something like key(topic, hour), value(rating) ? 

Are there any chance I could get you to help me out with a conceptual example perhaps?

Comment: `key(topic, hour), value(rating, num)` sounds good. You want the *average rating* for each *topic and hour*. You can also use the finalize function to add the keys to the final objects (currently it will only create objects which consist of the fields num, total and average, but without any context).

Comment: Reading through your answer again, got me thinking about what you want me to do. In my map function, I should "create" a key, instead of using a "natural" key like this.Topic ? More specifically I should perhaps extract the hour info from this.created_at and combine this with the topic into a key. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Guess I was too fast my last commment! Just realising how powerful MapReduce is. Thank you for your help!